# Can I create a field that is conditionally assigned by date in SQL?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, window-functions

I'm dealing with some subscription data. When the user upgrades/downgrades, the system overwrites the level of the subscription with the new value. I am trying to assign the historical values when the user has upgraded. My data set looks like the following where one user can upgrade or downgrade multiple times.
I am trying to get the what is outlined in the "desired value" column.

Essentially, and transactions that happened before an upgrade should be assigned the "original_product" that is captured on the upgrade transaction, transactions that happen after this should be assigned the "new_product" value.

I've been trying joining the data to itself, but I can't find a way to avoid getting multiple rows for each invoice.

[image: table example]

Answer (score 1):

You can use window functions:

```
select t.*,
       coalesce(last_value(case when event = 'Upgrade' then new_product end ignore nulls) over (partition by sub_id order by created),
                first_value(original_product ignore nulls) over (partition by sub_id order by created)
               ) as desired_value
from t;
```

This gets the most recent `new_product` from an "Upgrade" row.  If that doesn't exist, then it gets the overall `original_product`.

Comment: I am able to get the products following the upgrade to work, but not able to get those before it to work with this logic. ```SELECT e.*, 
       coalesce(last_value(case when (event  ='Upgrade' OR event = "Downgrade" OR event = "Crossgrade") then new_product end ignore nulls) over (partition by subscription order by created),
                first_value(original_product ignore nulls) over (partition by subscription order by created)
               ) as desired_value

FROM  e```

Comment: @SarahLinkenhoker . . . Does the `first_value()` work by itself?  That seems to be the logic you want for the preceding products.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want `first_value()`:

```
select 
    t.*,
    coalesce(
        first_value(new_product ignore nulls) over(
            order by created desc
            rows between unboundeed preceding and current row
        ),
        first_value(original_product ignore nulls) over(
            order by created
            rows between current row and unbounded following 
        )
    ) desired_value
from mytable t
```

The idea is to first try to get the first non-null `new_product` value on preceding rows (current row included). If there is no such row, then we lookup the first non-null `original product` in the following rows.

In theory, you would also need a `partition by` clause that contains the column that represent the user. Your data has no sign of such column though, so I left it apart.

Answer (score 1):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL 
SELECT *, 
  IFNULL(
    FIRST_VALUE(original_product IGNORE NULLS) OVER(original_product_lookup),
    FIRST_VALUE(new_product IGNORE NULLS) OVER(new_product_lookup)
  ) AS desired_value
FROM `project.dataset.table` 
WINDOW 
  original_product_lookup AS (ORDER BY created ROWS BETWEEN 1 FOLLOWING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING),
  new_product_lookup AS (ORDER BY created DESC ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)
```

You can test, play with above using simplified data from your question (using only used/relevant data-points) as in below example

```
#standardSQL 
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 1 created, NULL original_product, NULL new_product UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, NULL, NULL UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 'Level 1', 'Level 2' UNION ALL
  SELECT 4, NULL, NULL UNION ALL
  SELECT 5, 'Level 2', 'Level 1' UNION ALL
  SELECT 6, NULL, NULL 
)
SELECT *, 
  IFNULL(
    FIRST_VALUE(original_product IGNORE NULLS) OVER(original_product_lookup),
    FIRST_VALUE(new_product IGNORE NULLS) OVER(new_product_lookup)
  ) AS desired_value
FROM `project.dataset.table` 
WINDOW 
  original_product_lookup AS (ORDER BY created ROWS BETWEEN 1 FOLLOWING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING),
  new_product_lookup AS (ORDER BY created DESC ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)
ORDER BY created
```

with result

```
Row created original_product    new_product desired_value    
1   1       null                null        Level 1  
2   2       null                null        Level 1  
3   3       Level 1             Level 2     Level 2  
4   4       null                null        Level 2  
5   5       Level 2             Level 1     Level 1  
6   6       null                null        Level 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Was able to solve with the combination of answers

```
SELECT e.*, 
       coalesce(
        last_value(case when (event  ='Upgrade' OR event = "Downgrade" OR event = "Crossgrade") then new_product end ignore nulls) over (partition by subscription order by created),
        
         first_value(original_product ignore nulls) over(
            order by created
            rows between current row and unbounded following 
        )
    ) desired_value

FROM  e
```